# Using Ninject with MVVM Light

Tags: c#, wpf, ninject, mvvm-light

Using MVVM Light in a WPF MVVM application.

I want to use Ninject instead of SimpleIOC.

Even in a brand new WPF/MVVM Light v4 project, I get a null reference for MainViewModel when the Main Property in the ViewModelLocator is called by the XAML.

```
 private static readonly StandardKernel kernel;

    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            kernel = new StandardKernel(new mymodule());
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get { return kernel.Get<MainViewModel>(); }
    }
```

MyModule looks like this:

```
    public class mymodule:NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<MainViewModel>().ToSelf();
    }
}
```

I've also tried

```
    public class mymodule:NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<MainViewModel>().To<MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is kernel.Get<MainViewModel> returning null or is kernel null?

Comment: In case exceptions are involved, always provide the full exception type, message and stacktrace along the sample code.

Answer (score 3):

Ninject kernel's `.Get<T>` does not return null.

Except in case you explicitly tell it to by doing:

- `Bind<T>().ToConstant(null);`
- `Bind<T>().ToMethod(x => null);`
- `Bind<T>().ToProvider<TProvider>()` --> and `TProvider.Create(...)` returns null

It's very unlikely you have any of these.
So if there's a `NullReferenceException` when accessing the `Main` property, it must be because `private static readonly StandardKernel kernel` is null.
Now if the code you've provided us is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that means `ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic` returns `true`.